# How to create a custom, reusable datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I often find myself using datagrids that are read only with selection disabled. When I run into this issue I always have to look back at old projects to determine the settings I need to use. I know there has to be a way to create a custom version of this control with the proper settings saved.

The first thing I did was create 2 resource dictionaries with the settings I would like to reuse stored in their own assembly. From what I am reading this is not the best solution because it can be costly to share resource dictionaries.

Read only resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Chapman.ClientTemplate.Views">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Selection Disabled resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>

<!-- blah blah found this code online somewhere and seemed to work. -->
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I attempted to create a custom datagrid like so:

```
public class ReadOnlyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public ReadOnlyDataGrid()
        : base()
    {
        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new System.Windows.ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApp.Wpf;component/DataGridReadOnly.xaml")
        });

        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new System.Windows.ResourceDictionary()
        {
            Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApp.Wpf;component/DataGridSelectDisabled.xaml")
        });
    }
}
```

However, for some reason this does not seem to properly apply my styles. Also, I dont like the way I have to load the resource dictionaries using a hardcoded uri like this. It doesnt seem right. Can someone suggest a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you need only a readonly datagrid style then use this:

1. Define the style with the key "ReadonlyDataGrid" in a resource dictionary

For example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="ReadonlyDataGrid">
        <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
```

2. Add the resource dictionary to your application

For example:

```
<Application x:Class="Dashboard.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Core.Client;component/Styles/DataGrid.xaml"/>            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

3. Use the style by your application datagrid

For example:

```
<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource ReadonlyDataGrid}"/>
```

Comment: The project that will be using this resource dictionary is a control library and does not have an App.xaml. I can reference it directly from the control's resources but I read that this can cause the resource dictionary to be loaded multiple times creating unnecessary overhead. Is there another way to load the resource dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a code snippet and share it with any developers that need it on a  shared drive?

This would avoid using a resource dictionary.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx